# Php how to go one level down on dirname(__FILE__)?

Tags: php

with this code I get filename from the current folder

```
<?php 
  $mydir = dirname(__FILE__);
  $myfiles = array_diff(scandir($mydir), array('.', '..')); 
  $arrsingleresult = str_replace('.php', '', $myfiles);
  print_r($arrsingleresult);
?>
```

Now how can I get filenames from one folder back ? (../ like this) any work around ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Anything not working when using `$mydir . '../'` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please use double time dirname() function to back one level
>
> `dirname(dirname(__FILE__));`